# Change value of column using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Can I do something like below with `CASE` in SQL Server

```
(Case When location = 'Columbia' Then (direction = 942) Else direction End) as newdirection
```

Originally Columbia's direction is 941.

Comment: Yes, you can, what is your issue exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the assignment expression, just return the 942. You also don't need the parentheses:

```sql
Case When location = 'Columbia' Then 942 Else direction End as newdirection
```

Comment: Yes, and the OP is creating a new column in the result set, Just to be clear, they are not modifying an existing column.